# What are the differences between saveAsTable and insertInto in different SaveMode(s)?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to write a `DataFrame` into `Hive` table (on `S3`) in `Overwrite` mode (necessary for my application) and need to decide between two methods of DataFrameWriter (Spark / Scala). From what I can read in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter), `df.write.saveAsTable` differs from `df.write.insertInto` in the following respects:

- `saveAsTable` uses **column-name based resolution** while `insertInto` uses **position-based resolution**
- In Append mode, `saveAsTable` pays more attention to underlying schema of the existing table to make certain resolutions

Overall, it gives me the impression that `saveAsTable` is just a *smarter version* of `insertInto`. Alternatively, depending on use-case, one might prefer `insertInto`

But do each of these methods come with some caveats of their own like performance penalty in case of `saveAsTable` (since it packs in more features)? Are there any other differences in their behaviours apart from what is told (not very clearly) in the docs?

---

**EDIT-1**

Documentation says this regarding `insertInto`

> Inserts the content of the DataFrame to the specified table

and this for `saveAsTable`

> In the case the table already exists, behavior of this function
>   depends on the save mode, specified by the mode function

Now I can list my doubts

- Does `insertInto` always expect the table to exist?
- Do `SaveMode`s have any impact on `insertInto`?
- If above answer is yes, then

  - what's the differences between `saveAsTable` with `SaveMode.Append` and `insertInto` given that table already exists?
  - does `insertInto` with `SaveMode.Overwrite` make any sense?

Comment: All the QAs / links I've come across complain that Spark intrinsically overwrites all partitions (in Overwrite mode) and that some tricks are needed to bypass this rather inhibiting shortcoming

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER** I've been exploring `insertInto` for some time and although I'm far from an expert in this area I'm sharing the findings for greater good.

> Does `insertInto` always expect the table to exist?

[Yes](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/Analyzer.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L651) (per the table name and the database).

Moreover not all tables can be inserted into, i.e. a (permanent) table, a temporary view or a temporary global view are fine, but not:

1. a bucketed table
2. an RDD-based table

> Do SaveModes have any impact on insertInto?

(That's recently been my question, too!)

Yes, but only [SaveMode.Overwrite](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala#L317). After you think about `insertInto` the other 3 save modes don't make much sense (as it simply inserts a dataset).

> what's the differences between saveAsTable with SaveMode.Append and insertInto given that table already exists?

That's a very good question! I'd say none, but let's see by just one example (hoping that proves *something*).

```
scala> spark.version
res13: String = 2.4.0-SNAPSHOT

sql("create table my_table (id long)")
scala> spark.range(3).write.mode("append").saveAsTable("my_table")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: The format of the existing table default.my_table is `HiveFileFormat`. It doesn't match the specified format `ParquetFileFormat`.;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PreprocessTableCreation$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(rules.scala:117)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PreprocessTableCreation$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(rules.scala:76)
...
scala> spark.range(3).write.insertInto("my_table")
scala> spark.table("my_table").show
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  2|
|  0|
|  1|
+---+
```

> does insertInto with SaveMode.Overwrite make any sense?

I think so given it pays so much attention to `SaveMode.Overwrite`. It simply re-creates the target table.

```
spark.range(3).write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("my_table")
scala> spark.table("my_table").show
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  1|
|  0|
|  2|
+---+

Seq(100, 200, 300).toDF.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("my_table")
scala> spark.table("my_table").show
+---+
| id|
+---+
|200|
|100|
|300|
+---+
```

Comment: Hi Jacek, do you have any theory why saveAsTable behaves like this re: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException?

Comment: Looks like only Hive tables that Spark creates (ParquetFileFormat) are supported?

Comment: is there a particular reason you used `insertInto` instead of `saveAsTable` in your example? Would you expect them to behave differently?

Comment: The only reason I used `insertInto` instead of `saveAsTable` in my example was that the question specifically asked about the behaviour of `insertInto` per `SaveMode` / `mode`.

Comment: actually i want to write into a partitioned table for the first time in append mode , its failing with the same format issue . df.write.partitionBy("code").mode("append").format("orc").saveAsTable("test.t1")

Comment: @AviralKumar are you able to solve the format issue? If yes, please tell how.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Tanks for your contribution ;-). One question...When you work with an external Hive Metastore... saveAsTable (in overwrite mode) drops the table and partitions in Hive metastore, right? Does this make it more efficient work with insert Into to avoid msck repair, refresh table etc...? Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @ChristianHerreraJiménez I've got no idea (and would not be surprised to find out that it varies version by version). You'd simply be better off checking it out yourself by comparing query plans (and perhaps looking at the source code a bit).

Answer (score 17):

I want to point out a major difference between `SaveAsTable` and `insertInto` in SPARK.

In partitioned table `overwrite` SaveMode work differently in case of `SaveAsTable` and `insertInto`.

Consider below example.Where I am creating partitioned table using `SaveAsTable` method.

```
hive> CREATE TABLE `db.companies_table`(`company` string) PARTITIONED BY ( `id` date);
OK
Time taken: 0.094 seconds
```

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._*
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

scala>val targetTable = "db.companies_table"

scala>val companiesDF = Seq(("2020-01-01", "Company1"), ("2020-01-02", "Company2")).toDF("id", "company")

scala>companiesDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).partitionBy("id").saveAsTable(targetTable)

scala> spark.sql("select * from db.companies_table").show()
+--------+----------+
| company|        id|
+--------+----------+
|Company1|2020-01-01|
|Company2|2020-01-02|
+--------+----------+
```

Now I am adding 2 new rows with 2 new partition values.

```
scala> val companiesDF = Seq(("2020-01-03", "Company1"), ("2020-01-04", "Company2")).toDF("id", "company")

scala> companiesDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy("id").saveAsTable(targetTable)

scala>spark.sql("select * from db.companies_table").show()

+--------+----------+                                                           
| company|        id|
+--------+----------+
|Company1|2020-01-01|
|Company2|2020-01-02|
|Company1|2020-01-03|
|Company2|2020-01-04|
+--------+----------+
```

As you can see 2 new rows are added to the table.

Now let`s say i want to `Overwrite` partition 2020-01-02 data.

```
scala> val companiesDF = Seq(("2020-01-02", "Company5")).toDF("id", "company")

scala>companiesDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).partitionBy("id").saveAsTable(targetTable)
```

As per our logic only partitions 2020-01-02 should be overwritten but the case with `SaveAsTable` is different.It will overwrite the enter table as you can see below.

```
scala> spark.sql("select * from db.companies_table").show()
+-------+----------+
|company|        id|
+-------+----------+
|Company5|2020-01-02|
+-------+----------+
```

So if we want to overwrite only certain partitions in the table using `SaveAsTable` its not possible.

Refer this Link for more details.
https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-the-spark-insertinto-function-1870175c3ee9

Comment: Take note that this only happened for managed table. External table can use the config `spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode` set to dynamic and then refresh the table (`msck repair table ..`)

Comment: Yes @Joshua H. I wanted to update partitions in an external table and I can do that using 
```df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy('<col>') .option("partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic").option('path', '<location>') .saveAsTable(op_result_table)```

Answer (score 6):

I recently started converting my Hive Scripts to Spark and I am still learning.

There is one important behavior I noticed with saveAsTable and insertInto which has not been discussed.

df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("schema.table") drops the existing table "schema.table" and recreates a new table based on the 'df' schema. The schema of the existing table becomes irrelevant and does not have to match with df. I got bitten by this behavior since my existing table was ORC and the new table created was parquet (Spark Default).

df.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("schema.table") does not drop the existing table and expects the schema of the existing table to match with the schema of 'df'.

I checked the Create Time for the table using both options and reaffirmed the behavior.

Original Table stored as ORC -  **Wed Sep 04 21:27:33 GMT 2019**

After saveAsTable (storage changed to Parquet) - **Wed Sep 04 21:56:23 GMT 2019** (Create Time changed)

Dropped and Recreated origina table (ORC) - **Wed Sep 04 21:57:38 GMT 2019**

After insertInto (Still ORC) - **Wed Sep 04 21:57:38 GMT 2019** (Create Time Not changed)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the overall differences in summary table.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another important point that I do consider while inserting data into an EXISTING Hive dynamic partitioned table from spark 2.xx :

```
df.write.mode("append").insertInto("dbName"."tableName")
```

Above command will intrinsically map the data in your "df" and append only new partitions to existing table.

Hope, it adds another point in deciding when to use "insertInto".