# Spark not able to write into a new hive table in partitioned and append mode

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, orc

1. Created a new table in hive in `partitioned` and `ORC` format.
2. Writing into this table using spark by using `append` ,`orc` and `partitioned` mode.

It fails with the exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: The format of the existing table test.table1 is `HiveFileFormat`. It doesn't match the specified format `OrcFileFormat`.;
```

3. I change the format to "hive" from "orc" while writing . It still fails with the exception :
   Spark not able to understand the underlying structure of table .

So this issue is happening because `spark is not able to write into hive table in append mode , because it cant create a new table` . I am able to do `overwrite successfully because spark creates a table again`.

But my use case is to write into append mode from starting. `InsertInto also does not work specifically for partitioned tables`. I am pretty much blocked with my use case. Any help would be great.

**Edit1:**
Working on HDP 3.1.0 environment.

Spark Version is 2.3.2

Hive Version is 3.1.0

**Edit 2:**

```
// Reading the table 
val inputdf=spark.sql("select id,code,amount from t1")

//writing into table
inputdf.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy("code").format("orc").saveAsTable("test.t2")
```

**Edit 3: Using insertInto()**

```
val df2 =spark.sql("select id,code,amount from t1")
df2.write.format("orc").mode("append").insertInto("test.t2");
```

**I get the error as:**

```
20/05/17 19:15:12 WARN SessionState: METASTORE_FILTER_HOOK will be ignored, since hive.security.authorization.manager is set to instance of HiveAuthorizerFactory.
20/05/17 19:15:12 WARN SessionState: METASTORE_FILTER_HOOK will be ignored, since hive.security.authorization.manager is set to instance of HiveAuthorizerFactory.
20/05/17 19:15:13 WARN AcidUtils: Cannot get ACID state for test.t1 from null
20/05/17 19:15:13 WARN AcidUtils: Cannot get ACID state for test.t1 from null
20/05/17 19:15:13 WARN HiveMetastoreCatalog: Unable to infer schema for table test.t1 from file format ORC (inference mode: INFER_AND_SAVE). Using metastore schema.
```

**If I rerun the insertInto command I get the following exception :**

```
20/05/17 19:16:37 ERROR Hive: MetaException(message:The transaction for alter partition did not commit successfully.)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$alter_partitions_req_result$alter_partitions_req_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$alter_partitions_req_result$alter_partitions_req_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
```

Error in hive metastore logs :

```
2020-05-17T21:17:43,891 INFO  [pool-8-thread-198]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:logInfo(907)) - 163: alter_partitions : tbl=hive.test.t1
2020-05-17T21:17:43,891 INFO  [pool-8-thread-198]: HiveMetaStore.audit (HiveMetaStore.java:logAuditEvent(349)) - ugi=X@A.ORG  ip=10.10.1.36   cmd=alter_partitions : tbl=hive.test.t1
2020-05-17T21:17:43,891 INFO  [pool-8-thread-198]: metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:alter_partitions_with_environment_context(5119)) - New partition values:[BR]
2020-05-17T21:17:43,913 ERROR [pool-8-thread-198]: metastore.ObjectStore (ObjectStore.java:alterPartitions(4397)) - Alter failed
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetaException: Cannot change stats state for a transactional table without providing the transactional write state for verification (new write ID -1, valid write IDs null; current state null; new state {}
```

Comment: What's the version of Hadoop/Hive/Spark and/or what's the platform you're working at?

Comment: Show us the code where you're trying to insert into table.

Comment: edited again with the intented code

Comment: And create statement for the  `test.t2` ?

Comment: create table test.t2 (id bigint,amount double) partitioned by (code string) stored as ORC;

Comment: Try remove `.format("orc")` and/or replace with `.format("hive")`

Comment: I have already tried that and mentioned the same in question also . It does not work .

Comment: WARN HiveMetastoreCatalog: Unable to infer schema for table t1 from file format ORC (inference mode: INFER_AND_SAVE). Using metastore schema. I get this warning while reading and writing also.

Comment: In general you shouldn't specify format for existing table. Partitioning should also be done at Hive side. Also the order of columns matters. The partitioning column should be the last one in the dataframe.

Comment: df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).insertInto("test.t2")

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47844808/what-are-the-differences-between-saveastable-and-insertinto-in-different-savemod

Comment: I am not sure if the partition column location really matters and when I tried the above command I get this WARN Hive: No partition is generated by dynamic partitioning
WARN HiveMetastoreCatalog: Unable to infer schema for table test.t2 from file format ORC (inference mode: INFER_AND_SAVE). Using metastore schema.

Comment: Well, I don't have the particular setup to test, so guessing. And if you bring back partitioning, but using `insertInto` instead `saveAsTable`?

Comment: robert thats the same case which I have reported in the question , removed format("ORC") also does not help as it assumes the target table is in parquet file format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214003/discussion-between-robert-navado-and-aviral-kumar).

Comment: can you show your hive table create statement ?

Comment: create table test.t2 (id bigint,amount double) partitioned by (code string) stored as ORC;

Comment: were you able to get the solution?

Comment: By using external table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by using external tables in my use case. We currently have an open issue in spark , which is related to acid properties of hive . Once I create hive table in external mode , I am able to do append operations in partitioned/non partitioned table. 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15348