# apache spark sql table overwrite issue

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am using the below code to create a table from a dataframe in databricks and run into error.

```
df.write.saveAsTable("newtable")
```

This works fine the very first time but for re-usability if I were to rewrite like below

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("newtable")
```

I get the following error.

***Error Message:***

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can not create the managed table newtable. The associated location dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/newtable already exists
```

Answer (score 5):

The SQL config 'spark.sql.legacy.allowCreatingManagedTableUsingNonemptyLocation' was removed in the version 3.0.0. It was removed to prevent loosing of users data for non-default value.

Answer (score 3):

- [What are the differences between saveAsTable and insertInto in different SaveMode(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47844808/what-are-the-differences-between-saveastable-and-insertinto-in-different-savemod)

**Run following command to fix issue :**

```
     dbutils.fs.rm("dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/newtable/", true)
```

Or

Set the flag

`spark.sql.legacy.allowCreatingManagedTableUsingNonemptyLocation = true`

`spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.allowCreatingManagedTableUsingNonemptyLocation","true")`

Comment: Hi @vaquar khan, Thank you for the response. I still get error and not sure why can't I use saveAsTable with the overwrite. Also, databricks documentation suggests against using dbutils.fs.rm on large datasets.(https://kb.databricks.com/data/list-delete-files-faster.html)

Comment: Try this.      Set the flag spark.sql.legacy.allowCreatingManagedTableUsingNonemptyLocation to true